# Where is a working, relatively easy to use mneumonic converter for Tezos?

Tags: encrypted, secret, secret-key

A little request to baking bad, or TezTech, or anyone else who wants to create this.

I have a reqeust to have a mneumonic code coverter for bip39(tz1),Secp256k1(tz2), NIST P256(tz3) created, similar to this website

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

BIP39 - Mnemonic Code 2
There is also also created an offline version which I use regularly for encrypting and decrypting my ethereum address when I feel like changing the private key encryption password for myself or my customers. It works really well, and I find myself using it 5-6 times a week just trying to sort out peoples ethereum/erc20 wallket issues.

Looking around on google, you were able to do it with eztz

GitHub 1

https://github.com/TezTech/eztzTezos

and I used it in the past(2 years ago), but it is outdated and doesn’t seem to work anymore.

Smartpy also seems to have a solution, but, a lot of people are getting the
TypeError: ‘secret_key’ is an invalid keyword argument for this function error, and it only seems to work on certain versions of pi.

If we could get a tool, a simple static html file to encrypt and unencrypted these secret/encypted files like ethereum, it would make life a lot easier for a mid-career engineers to help out the end users of the Tezos protocol.

Anyways, sorry for posting this here, I feel like this will get the most attention, and if there is a solution out there, feel free to post it here and I will make an in depth tutorial so other users can take advantage of this tool.

Warm regards,

Mack(KryptStar Staking)

Comment: There is no tool for this right now, besides figuring out how to do it on SmartPy.  however you can re-encrypt your secret key by going to https://wallet.tezbox.com/ and entering your secret key and password.  Go to settings and change the network(default network is down) change to -> https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io.  From there go to "options" and show secret key.  copy your unencrypted key.

Comment: From the tezos-client(command line interface), encrypt the key with ->
"./tezos-client encrypt secret key" (follow the prompt and input your unencrypted private key and the encryption password).  to double check it works, import the key using "./tezos-client import secret <alias> encrypted:edesk<key>" and input the password again and see if it's the same address.  Not a direct answer(will wait till a dev can make a proper solution).